# Time inequality between days not working

Tags: android, time, textview, inequality

I need to set a text on a text view based on time.
If the inequality is within the day (from 5:00 to 7:30) I use:

```
if     (today.month == 7 &&
            today.monthDay == 7 &&
           (today.hour > 5 || (today.hour == 5 && today.minute >= 00)) &&
           (today.hour < 7 || (today.hour == 7 && today.minute <= 30)))
   {DubAcademy.setText("A");}
```

The problem is that this code is not working for hours that go from one day to the next (i.e. 23:00 to 1:00 of the day after). I have tried this, but is not working

```
if     (today.month == 7 &&
            today.monthDay == 6 &&
           (today.hour > 23 || (today.hour == 23 && today.minute >= 00)) &&
           (today.monthDay <= 7 || (today.monthDay == 7 && today.hour <= 01 && today.minute <= 00 )))
   {DubAcademy.setText("B");}
```

I know that it is because the month day is set to be 6, therefore, when date changes, the equation is no longer valid and no text is displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, maybe i am wrong, but you don't have a code problem you have a logic problem, so, my advice to you, first do a flow diagram
https://www.draw.io/
 and check yout logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(today.month == 7 
    && ((today.monthDay == 6 && today.hour >= 23)
    ||  (today.monthDay == 7 && (today.hour < 1 || (today.hour == 1 && today.minute == 00)))
```

Today.minute should always be >= 00 so it seems silly to check that.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use 2 `Time` objects as the boundary for cleaner code. Set the first time to the time you want (for range that finishes until the next day, proper modification is needed). Then set the second time relative to the first one for simplified manipulation. Lastly, call [`normalize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#normalize%28boolean%29) to ensure its values are correct. Then you can just use `after()` and `before()` to check if the time is in range or not.

```
Time today = new Time();
today.setToNow();

Time t1 = new Time(today);
if(today.hour < 1){
    t1.monthDay--; // set date to yesterday
}
t1.hour = 23;
t1.minute = 0;
t1.second = 0;

Time t2 = new Time(t1);
t2.hour += 2;
t2.normalize(true);
// Android will ensure the value in each field are in range 

if(today.after(t1) && today.before(t2)){
    // do something here
}
```